# How to define an array in hadoop partitioner

Tags: arrays, hadoop, mapreduce

I am new in hadoop and mapreduce programming and don't know what should i do.  I want to define an array of int in hadoop partitioner. i want to feel in this array in main function and use its content in partitioner. I have tried to use `IntWritable` and array of it but none of them didn't work . I tried to use `IntArrayWritable` but again it didn't work. I will be pleased if some one help me. Thank you so much

```
public static IntWritable h = new IntWritable[1];

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    h[0] = new IntWritable(1);
}

public static class CaderPartitioner extends Partitioner <Text,IntWritable> {

    @Override
    public int getPartition(Text key, IntWritable value, int numReduceTasks) {
        return h[0].get();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have limited number of values, you can do in the below way.
set the values on the configuration object like below in main method.

```
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.setInt("key1", value1);
    conf.setInt("key2", value2);
```

Then implement the Configurable interface for your Partitioner class and get the configuration object, then key/values from it inside your Partitioner

```
 public class testPartitioner extends Partitioner<Text, IntWritable> implements Configurable{

Configuration config = null;

@Override
public int getPartition(Text arg0, IntWritable arg1, int arg2) {

    //get your values based on the keys in the partitioner
    int value = getConf().getInt("key");
    //do stuff on value

    return 0;
}

@Override
public Configuration getConf() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.config;
}

@Override
public void setConf(Configuration configuration) {
    this.config = configuration;

 }  
}
```

supporting link
https://cornercases.wordpress.com/2011/05/06/an-example-configurable-partitioner/

note if you have huge number of values in a file then better to find a way to get cache files from job object in Partitioner

Answer (score 1):

Here's a refactored version of the partitioner. The main changes are:

1. Removed the `main()` which isnt needed, initialization should be done in the constructor
2. Removed static from the class and member variables

---

```
public class CaderPartitioner extends Partitioner<Text,IntWritable> {

    private IntWritable[] h;

    public CaderPartitioner() {
        h = new IntWritable[1];
        h[0] = new IntWritable(1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getPartition(Text key, IntWritable value, int numReduceTasks) {
        return h[0].get();
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

- `h` doesn't need to be a Writable, unless you have additional logic not included in the question.
- It isn't clear what the `h[]` is for, are you going to configure it? In which case the partitioner will probably need to `implement Configurable` so you can use a `Configurable` object to set the array up in some way.

Comment: Thanks. but i want to feel h[0] from main function. main function is has configuration codes. for example i have temp[0] that in main function i modify it. then i want to copy temp[0] to h[0] in partitioner. thanks

Comment: You can't use a `main()` method. You need to encapsulate everything within the partitioner.

Comment: Thank you so much. i have a file that has some keys and reduce number. i want to read this file and decide reducer for each key using this information. do you have an opinion to help me to do this?

Comment: I think you've asked that in another question. I'll take a look and let you know if i have any thoughts. If you're happy with this answer please upvote/accept it.